Django distinct and group_by query using the ORM and MySQL
I'd like to obtain a QuerySet containing all the latest comments for each post using Django ORM. The comments can be ordered by the when field.
Suppose the following example:
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()


class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    when = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

This in raw SQL could be achieved, so I assume Django may have its own way too. I'd like to avoid using raw queries (discouraged by Django documentation).
I cannot use distinct() with fields names as I am using MySQL.
Any indication is appreciated.
EDIT
Since I could not find a solution in Django, I had to (disappointingly) use raw queries.
The one I am using is:
data = Post.objects.raw("""
            SELECT * FROM `myapp_post`
            INNER JOIN `myapp_comment` AS t1
            ON `myapp_post`.`id` = t1.`post_id`
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT post_id, MAX(`when`) AS latest
                FROM `myapp_comment`
                GROUP BY post_id
            ) AS t2
                ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id AND
                t1.`when` = t2.latest
        """)

I doubt this is the best solution, though. If anyone is able to translate the above in the Django ORM language, shout it out please!

Why is the ForeignKey named author when it refers to a Post?

Sorry, typo fixed.

We can work with a FilteredRelation [Django-doc] here:
from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, OuterRef, Q

Post.objects.annotate(
    latest_comment=FilteredRelation(
        'comment_set',
        condition=Q(
            comment=Subquery(
                Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk'))
                .order_by('-when')
                .values('pk')[:1]
            ),
        ),
    ),
).select_related('latest_comment')

I get FilteredRelation.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'condition__pk'

@decadenza: sorry, it was condition.

Thank you for your help. This seems much more complicated that in raw SQL.
After using condition I get FilteredRelation's relation_name cannot contain lookups (got 'comment__set').

But it is comment_set, not comment__set.

Well I originally though that was another typo. BTW, in that case I get Cannot resolve keyword 'comment_set' into field.

@decadenza: did you specify a related_name=... in the ForeignKey?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
